# Preloading files in WebView for ePub or PDF reader

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, reader

I'm developing an ePub reader, and I receive the files after each other. So it will load the first xhtml when I start my reader (this is needed because I don't want to download the whole ePub when I start the reader).

Right now When a user scrolls (horizontal) through the pages of an epub and transitions from one file to another, there is a short loading time (because it is retrieving the next xhtml from the server).

Right now, it is a jarring experience, preventing the user from scrolling forward. When the next file is loaded, the page jumps to the new one.

It would be better to let the user 'scroll' to the next file like any other page, but while the new file is loading, show a blank page with a loading icon. The page is then replaced by the actual one when the file is loaded.

I'm currently working with a UIWebView, because the WKWebView does not support pagination.

Does someone know a solution for this?